# Passwords in Chrome

Tags: macos, password, google-chrome

I forgot one of my passwords stored in Chrome. When I navigate to the page Chrome offers to auto-fill it in. I need to know the password. I checked Settings, it says

```
View and manage saved passwords in your [Google Account][1]

**Saved Passwords**
*Saved passwords will appear here*

**Never Saved**
...
```

I checked https://passwords.google.com and there are indeed passwords listed there, but not the particular one I am looking for. I looked in chrome://flags/ and there is no password export option there (there might have been before). My version is

Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Is there any easy way to find this password other than with wireshark?

Comment: after you went to the page did you click the eye icon

Comment: what eye icon 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2tgaoll61qh5dq/Screenshot%202019-02-08%2011.55.22.png

Comment: https://passwords.google.com/ then look for the website then click the eye icon to view it

Comment: good idea, except -- as I indicated very clearly in the question -- this website is not on that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect the input element for the password and change the input type from password to text. You will notice the password that has been filled in will be visible (changed from ******).

1. Right click on the password field on the website and click 'Inspect' from the context menu.
2. This will open developer tools with the input element selected. It will be something like `<input type="password" ..>`. Change the type to `text` and click outside. This will save the change and you will see your password.

[image: dev tools]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @abdul's answer, you can use Firefox to import from Chrome and have a backup of the passwords. You can view all your passwords in Firefox as well.

Comment: that did not work: firefox only imports passwords that are locally saved in Chrome, not the ones in https://passwords.google.com

Comment: This may help you: https://lifehacker.com/moving-your-passwords-from-google-chrome-to-a-dedicated-1823644449

Comment: Trouble is, I also need a time machine as that extension is not available anymore in chrome flags.